# Flex AS3 warp transform image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, bitmap, transform

I am looking for an example / code /guideline to transform a bitmap like in the image bellow:
[image]

I've tried everything displacement map, matrix transform etc. but nothing even remotely works.

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: how about some math and copy pixels from original bitmap data to new bitmap data ?

Comment: that seems to be an idea, but in order to do that you must create something like a mask that has the desired shape and then apply the original image to it. Unfortunately i don't know how to do that either.